# Does garbage collection remove deleted items from a Doubly Linked List with the given code?

Tags: javascript, linked-list, garbage-collection, doubly-linked-list

I have a Doubly Linked List that each object has a data and a pointer to the next object and a pointer to the previous object like this:

`obj1 <-> obj2 <-> obj3 <-> obj4 <->`

I use this code to remove `obj3` and `obj4`: assume `p` is the data of `obj2`

```
let b = head;
while(b.next!=null){
b=b.next
if(b.data === p){
b.next = null;}}
```

In this way of deleting, the pointer to `obj3` is lost and so `obj3` and `obj4` are not accessible but `obj3` has the pointer to `obj2` in the `obj3.previous`

My question is: if I use this code to remove `obj3` and `obj4` will garbage collection remove `obj3` and `obj4` from the memory? If yes how does it understand that `obj3` is not accessible (will it iterate over the linked list? if yes will the operation take time of O(n)?). It is important to me to know how much the javascript garbage collection will slow down the runtime.(the list is so long and will take some time to iterate over)

Answer (score 2):

There are various garbage collection strategies that work fine with circular references, one of them being ['mark and sweep'](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection). Modern engines use these strategies. [V8 for example does so too](https://v8.dev/blog/orinoco-parallel-scavenger).

> if I use this code to remove obj 3 and obj 4 will garbage collection remove obj3 and 4 from the memory?

It *could*. Wether it really does depends pretty much on the way the garbage collector works.

> and if yes how does it undrestand that obj 3 is not accessible ?

If it uses mark and sweep, it'll follow all references from all variables onwards and *mark* all objects. Then it'll go through the heap and *sweep* all objects that are not marked.

> will the operation take time of O(n) ?

Yes. The more memory you use the more work has the garbage collector to do.

> because i am writing a code and its important to me that how much will javascript garbage collection slow down the code runtime

Then how about ... actually checking how fast your code is and how much time the garbage collection obtains?